# How to update GTalk to feature video chat?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, google-talk, video-calling

I would like to know if it is possible to 'force update' the Talk app. I have Nexus S and I have the video chat in my Talk, but my girlfriend with S Galaxy II (2.3.4) doesn't. I read somewhere on the internet that Talk should feature videochatting from 2.3.4 on, but well... It doesn't so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1056793) post from xda-developers will help you if her phone is rooted.

Comment: I was thinking about 'official' approach, rather than rooting. But I understand that this means there is no such way. It also turns out it's 2.3.3, she looked it up wrong..